# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY not working as intended with Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We are currently launching a website url which directs to a website and then redirects to a Google Play market link. It is launched like so

```
public static Intent createAdvertisementLaunchIntent(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    return intent;
}
```

When the user is on the market page, the intention is that when they press the back button, they should return to our application.

This works without issue on all devices and browsers except under one condition: when using Android 4.2.2, and only if the browser is open in the background.

In this situation when the user presses the back button, they are returned to Chrome with the previous active tab visible. Any further back button presses are handled by Chrome.

I have tried combining this intent with other flags like FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to no avail and my searches haven't brought any new ideas.

Is this a known issue or have I missed something?

Thank you

Comment: jimmithy, i see that this question was posted a few months ago. were you able to resolve this issue? if yes, do you mind updating this thread? I am trying to resolve something very similar issue. Thanks!